# How to post new message on a group wall

Tags: php, facebook, cron

I have a site with recipes and also the site has a groups in facebook with several thousands of friends. I want to post new recipes on the group timeline. I can do it with cron every 1 hour for example.

```
require_once('facebook.php');

    $config = array(
        'appId' => 'xxx',
        'secret' => 'xxx',
    );

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);

    // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
    try {
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/page_id/feed', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                    'link' => 'www.example.com',
                                    'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                                ));
        echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';

    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "error type: ". $e->getType()."<br />";
        echo "error mesage: ". $e->getMessage()."<br />";
    }
```

How should I change my script to be able to post on the groups page from cron daemon?

I changed the script little bit and now I have this error:
error type: OAuthException
error mesage: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxx',
    'secret' => 'xxx',
    'cookie' => true
);
```

Setting a cookie should keep you logged in.

Comment: Well, I see the problem now. You try to post your message - if that does not work, you log in. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: How can I authorize the app to perform this action ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the document [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/#links):

> Users can post a link on the Group's wall by issuing an HTTP POST
>   request to `/GROUP_ID/feed` with the `publish_actions` permissions and the
>   following parameters. (`publish_stream` will also work, but you should
>   use `publish_actions`.) This requires a user `access_token`.

So what you need to do to just post (run your script as the user):

1. `publish_actions` permission
2. the user `access_token`

Now to use this as cronjob, I usually do the following:

1. authorize the user (who has rights to publish to this group) with the required permission
2. [extend his token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/)
3. store this token in the DB
4. use the token to publish
5. keep an eye on the expiry variable and before, say, 3 days of token expiration --> send an email to the user to "login" to your app again and then go-to **#3**
6. always catch any error while posting and log it; you can check if the error is about the access token and hence go-to **#5**

Comment: Some sample code would have been brilliant here. To get the user's access_token you can use this method: `$facebook->getAccessToken()`. You do have to instantiate the $facebook object first. `$facebook = new Facebook($config);`